# Qt Meego Bluetooth Segmentation Fault

Tags: qt, bluetooth, segmentation-fault, meego, aegis

I have created a game that runs fine on Symbian but won't run on the Meego/Harmattan emulator. It gives me a lot of No AEGIS_HASH_FDS environment errors and a Segmentation fault. I think it may have something to do with QBluetooth because I have a version of the same app that doesn't use it which runs fine. What could be causing this and how do I use QBluetooth with Meego/Harmattan? If it helps I have also tried running the Bluetooth Chat example that comes with Qt on wich my app is based and it gives the exact same errors on the emulator.